# Transform $\tan$ to be continuous between $0$ and $1$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to create a $\tan$ function which has asymptotes between $0$ and $1.$

[This is the closest I have gotten](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x*10%2FPI%20%2B%20PI%2F2%29%20where%20x%20from%20-0.1%20to%201.1), but I can see that the asymptote is not actually at $1$ and when $x=0.5,\; y=0.02$. Close, but no cigar.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a linear transformation that takes $ 0$ to $\frac {-\pi}2$ and $1$ to $\frac \pi 2$ .  The scale factor is ${\pi}$ and the offset is $\frac \pi 2$.  So $y=\tan(\pi x-\frac \pi 2)$ as in [this alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%28x*PI%20-%20PI%2F2%29%20where%20x%20from%20-0.1%20to%201.1)

Comment: Thank you! I used to be good at this stuff when I was actually taking math courses. If you don't use it, you lose it!